# Getting the actual screen height (android)

Tags: java, android

I want to get the actual screen height of the device that runs my app. To achieve this i try the following:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int Height = metrics.heightPixels;
TextView HeightView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.screenHeight);
HeightView.setText("Screen Height: " + Height);

int Width = metrics.widthPixels;
TextView WidthView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.screenWidth);
WidthView.setText("Screen Width: " + Width);
```

The device that I run using the emulator has a screen width of 1080 pixels and a screen height of 1920 pixels. The width is displayed correctly (1080 pixels) but the height is according to the app only 1776 pixels. What do I need to make my app display the correct screen height? Is `metrics.heightPixels` a bad way of getting the screen height?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/5795310) answer

if your API level > 13 try this if you are in activity

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

If you're not in an Activity you can get the default Display via WINDOW_SERVICE:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)    context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

getWidth and getHeight is for API level 13 or less

**UPDATE**

For API 17 and higher method `Display.getRealSize()` returns full size of screen, as mentioned [in documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize(android.graphics.Point)):

> Gets the real size of the display
>   without subtracting any window decor or applying any compatibility
>   scale factors.
>
> The size is adjusted based on the current rotation of the display.
>
> The real size may be smaller than the physical size of the screen when
>   the window manager is emulating a smaller display (using adb shell am
>   display-size).

Answer (score 19):

```
int width=Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height=Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 7):

I needed to get the **actual** available height, and out of all the options this is the only thing that worked for me.

Create a rectangle, and get its dimensions:

```
Rect r = new Rect();
activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
int screenHeight = r.bottom - r.top;
```

where `activityRootView` is the root view of your layout.

If you need to extract the toolbar height:

```
int availableScreenHeight = screenHeight - toolbar.getHeight();
```

where `toolbar` is your toolbar view.

`availableScreenHeight` will now be without the statusbar, without the toolbar, and without the navigation bar (if the device is using it).

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code:

```
val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
val size = Point()
display.getSize(size)
val width: Int = size.x
val height: Int = size.y
```

Comment: This is just like the accepted answer, why publish a copy?

Comment: This is in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
 Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
 Point size = new Point();
 d.getSize(size);
 Log.i("LOG", "W=" + size.x + " , H=" + size.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this library: [TorryDo/ScreenEasy](https://github.com/TorryDo/ScreenEasy). (I'm the author btw)

```kotlin
ScreenEz.with(context) // call once, see the docs for java support.

val width = ScreenEz.fullWidth
val height = ScreenEz.fullHeight
...
```

With this, you won't have to worry about handling deprecated codes for different Android Versions.