# why it gives screen inch size wrong all the time?

Tags: android, screen-size, android-screen

I want to calculate device size by inch. I am using this code that every search appears. But the problem is when I put device 4.5 inch my answer in android studio is 4. I tried 5.2 inch device and I got 4.3 inch as well 10.1 inch -> the answer is 9.0. **So how can I get accurate answer?**

```
 DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    double wi=(double)dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi;
    double hi=(double)dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi;
    double x = Math.pow(wi,2);
    double y = Math.pow(hi,2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
    Log.e("hello"," "+screenInches);
```

Comment: You can use id for parent view. And then you can use your logic for parent which cover screen.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is it does not take into account

**Actionbar**

**Softkeys**

**Orientation of the screen**

use the following answer

```
 WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager();
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);

// since SDK_INT = 1;
mWidthPixels = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
mHeightPixels = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

// includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17)
{
    try
    {
        mWidthPixels = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth").invoke(display);
        mHeightPixels = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight").invoke(display);
    }
    catch (Exception ignored)
    {
    }
}

// includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
{
    try
    {
        Point realSize = new Point();
        Display.class.getMethod("getRealSize", Point.class).invoke(display, realSize);
        mWidthPixels = realSize.x;
        mHeightPixels = realSize.y;
    }
    catch (Exception ignored)
    {
    }


 DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(mWidthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
double y = Math.pow(mHeightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
Log.d("debug","Screen inches : " + screenInches);
```

credit to [him](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5789916/6478047)

Comment: thanks for the answer and I already tried this one too... i searched alot and tried alot before i wrote it here

Answer (score 1):

You can use **getResources().getDisplayMetrics()**

> DisplayMetrics: A structure describing general information about a
>   display,
>       such as its size, density, and font scaling.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int dens = metrics.densityDpi;
    double wi = (double)width / (double)dens;
    double hi = (double)height / (double)dens;
    double x = Math.pow(wi, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(hi, 2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);

    System.out.println("getSIZE"+screenInches);
```

For more information visit **[Android DisplayMetrics returns incorrect screen size.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991194/android-displaymetrics-returns-incorrect-screen-size-in-pixels-on-ics)**

Comment: thank for the answer but still i got 4.08 for 4.5 inch screen size

Comment: @Eazyz yes .Problem for `Bar` . Read above link .

Comment: i got Nan now for screen size :I

Comment: @Eazyz Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780980/getting-the-actual-screen-height-android

Answer (score 0):

Device Size is different from screen size as screen will not  cover total device size

Android OS has nothing to do with device size you cannot programatically get device dimensions you can get only screen dimensions

Comment: I want to get the inch to make layout for small devices so even 5.2 inch screen size not device screen return wrong answer

Comment: @Eazyz i didnt get what s your exact problem is

Answer (score 0):

**Try This With Just Small Change**

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int dens = metrics.densityDpi;
double wi = (double)width / (double)dens;
double hi = (double)height / (double)dens;
double x = Math.pow(wi, 2);
double y = Math.pow(hi, 2);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
try {
double screenInches = Double.parseDouble(df.format(Math.sqrt(x+y)));

Log.e("hello"," "+screenInches);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: thank for the answer..!
but it is the same still i got 4.08 for 4.5 inch screen

Comment: Not possible. How you got two digits after decimal point when you take in format as only single digit after decimal point.

Comment: Put your log response so I will get some idea why it happens.

Comment: 04-07 10:33:22.375 4775-4775/com.tsd.speakUp E/hello:  4.1

Comment: You will always get approx values

Comment: if it was approx why 5.2 inch gives me 4.3 inch

Comment: I will check for any external lib and let you know.

Comment: thanks actually i tried eveything and still can't get what i want and by the way my width and height is right but that math things gives the wrong answers

Comment: Math gives right answer but issue is manufacturing company will gives you standard size as specification but it will differ for different manufacture. Let say some specification shows 7 inch but actually hardware of display provides 6.7 ~ 6.8 something like that.

Comment: i get it but it is not close as u say
like 5.0 ,5.2 inch screens gives 4.4
5.5-->4.6 , 5.2-->4.6 , 10.1 -->9.1

Comment: I also got same its not even close.